# How to explicitly define URIs in symfony

Tags: routes, symfony1

My project is made from a couple of symfony apps. I would like to link them together through relative URIs, however, every time I define an anchor in a template and explicitly state path to another app, i.e.:

```
<a href="/backend">backend</a>
```

It gets prefixed with the current app's URI, like so:

```
<a href="/frontend/backend">backend</a>
```

What is the way to go around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use link_to helper?

```
<?= link_to('backend','@nameOfBackendRoute' ?>
```

First parameter is text to appear between anchor opening and closing tag, second argument is name of your route from routing.yml

More info can be found [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/UrlHelper#method_link_to)